# QML chartview crash when changing data

Tags: qt, qml

I'm new to qml and I didn't really get its logic yet.

Here is my issue: I have a chartview with barseries, and I expect that when the user clicks on a bar, the bar chart changes.

So I clear the barSeries and append new data to it. But it causes a segmentation fault.
If I do the same processing from a button click, it works well. 
Do you have any idea what is the problem, and how to fix it?

Below is a code sample.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

import QtCharts 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Chartview test")

    Item {
        id: histoView

        property int globalForJs: 0

        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: true

        Component.onCompleted: {
            redraw();
        }

        signal redrawSignal()

        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            Button {
                id:myBtn
                anchors { top: parent.top; left: parent.left; leftMargin: 20 }
                height: 30
                width: 80
                text: "new chart"
                onClicked: {
                    console.debug("myBtn onClicked")
                    histoView.redrawSignal()
                }
            }

            ChartView {
                id: chartView
                anchors { bottom: parent.bottom; left: parent.left; right: parent.right }
                height: parent.height - 40

                title: "chartview"

                BarSeries {
                    id: mySeries

                    axisX: BarCategoryAxis { categories: [" "] }
                    axisY: ValueAxis {
                        id: ordinate
                        min:0
                        max:100
                    }    

                    onClicked: {
                        console.debug("mySeries onClicked")
                        histoView.redrawSignal();
                        //myBtn.clicked()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function redraw() {
            // clear data
            mySeries.clear();

            // add 5 new data
            for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
                var tab=[];
                globalForJs++;
                tab.push(globalForJs);
                mySeries.append("tutu"+i,tab);
            }
            // update Y axis maximum value
            if (ordinate.max < globalForJs) {
                ordinate.max = globalForJs + 10;
            }
        }

        onRedrawSignal:redraw()
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer:

Looks like a bug in `QGraphicsScene` or Qt Charts' usage of it. Please report a bug at [bugreports.qt.io](http://bugreports.qt.io).

#### Long answer (debugging crashes in Qt):

When you run into a crash where there's only QML, and nothing suspicious-looking going on in your C++ code, it's probably a bug in Qt. In order to increase the changes of the bug being fixed quickly, it's a good idea to get a stack trace, because the developer may spot a simple fix for it by looking at where it crashes. To get a stack trace, you'll have to build a debug build of Qt.

When debugging your application with a debug build of Qt, I can see that `QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent()` is calling a member function of an object that has been deleted. An easy way to verify this is to add some debug code to the destructor of `QGraphicsItem` that prints out the memory address of each object that is destroyed. In addition, add a line to the beginning of `QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent()` that uses `qDebug()`'s `printf` syntax (to avoid `QGraphicsItem`'s `<<` operator being called, which would cause a crash before it could print anything):

```
diff --git a/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp b/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp
index f2b8b66..9f2302d 100644
--- a/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp
+++ b/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp
@@ -1501,6 +1501,7 @@ QGraphicsItem::QGraphicsItem(QGraphicsItemPrivate &dd, QGraphicsItem *parent)
 */
 QGraphicsItem::~QGraphicsItem()
 {
+    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << this;
     if (d_ptr->isObject) {
         QGraphicsObject *o = static_cast<QGraphicsObject *>(this);
         QObjectPrivate *p = QObjectPrivate::get(o);
@@ -7328,6 +7329,7 @@ void QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
 */
 void QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
 {
+    qDebug("About to access %p\n", this);
     if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && (flags() & ItemIsSelectable)) {
         bool multiSelect = (event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier) != 0;
         if (event->scenePos() == event->buttonDownScenePos(Qt::LeftButton)) {
```

Build `qtbase` and then debug your application again. The stack trace will now look something like this (copied from Creator):

```
1   QGraphicsItem::flags                          qgraphicsitem.cpp    1854 0x6dcf8cf9     
2   QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent              qgraphicsitem.cpp    7333 0x6dd05003     
3   QtCharts::Bar::mouseReleaseEvent              bar.cpp              90   0x7ffd83fd4a9b 
4   QGraphicsItem::sceneEvent                     qgraphicsitem.cpp    6845 0x6dd03ac6     
5   QGraphicsScenePrivate::sendEvent              qgraphicsscene.cpp   1251 0x6dd58732     
6   QGraphicsScenePrivate::sendMouseEvent         qgraphicsscene.cpp   1325 0x6dd594fd     
7   QGraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent             qgraphicsscene.cpp   4099 0x6dd52c26     
8   QGraphicsScene::event                         qgraphicsscene.cpp   3412 0x6dd51423     
9   QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper            qapplication.cpp     3713 0x6d7772de     
10  QApplication::notify                          qapplication.cpp     3085 0x6d771d83     
11  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2             qcoreapplication.cpp 1013 0x6cf72c16     
12  QCoreApplication::sendEvent                   qcoreapplication.h   231  0x6cf7d5f2     
13  QtCharts::DeclarativeChart::mouseReleaseEvent declarativechart.cpp 850  0x7ffd876dd16a 
14  QQuickItem::event                             qquickitem.cpp       7756 0x7ffd7e206583 
15  QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper            qapplication.cpp     3713 0x6d7772de     
16  QApplication::notify                          qapplication.cpp     3085 0x6d771d83     
17  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2             qcoreapplication.cpp 1013 0x6cf72c16     
18  QCoreApplication::sendEvent                   qcoreapplication.h   231  0x6cf7d5f2     
19  QQuickWindow::sendEvent                       qquickwindow.cpp     2807 0x7ffd7e2305f9 
20  QQuickWindowPrivate::deliverMouseEvent        qquickwindow.cpp     1671 0x7ffd7e235df1 
... <More>
```

Console output (shortened):

```
Debugging starts
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QML Debugger: Waiting for connection on port 52234...
[...]
__cdecl QGraphicsItem::~QGraphicsItem(void) QGraphicsItem(0x2da77915480, parent=0x2da77b0fc00, pos=0,0, flags=(ItemIsSelectable))
[...]
About to access 0x2da77915480
```

You can see that the `QGraphicsItem` whose memory address is `0x2da77915480` is destroyed, and then its `mouseReleaseEvent()` function is called.

Comment: Kudos to @Mitch. I wish all responses were this comprehensive.